# escape HTML make some attributes to have empty values

Tags: javascript, html

i am giving the user the ability to copy the html code of a div by clicking a button, some attributes such as for videos:

```
<video loop muted autoplay>
```

are becoming like this

```
<video loop="" muted="" autoplay="">
```

i have no idea why this is the case, this is my code for copying the content:

```
/*copy to clipboard */
function copyToClipboard() {

    // Create an auxiliary hidden input
    var aux = document.createElement("input");

    // Get the text from the element passed into the input
    aux.setAttribute("value", document.getElementById('sampleeditor').innerHTML);

    // Append the aux input to the body
    document.body.appendChild(aux);

    // Highlight the content
    aux.select();

    // Execute the copy command
    document.execCommand("copy");

    var tooltip = document.getElementById("myTooltip");

    tooltip.innerHTML = "Copied";
    // Remove the input from the body
    document.body.removeChild(aux);
    setTimeout(() => { tooltip.innerHTML = "Copy to clipboard"; }, 2000);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because they are an attribute with an empty value. The code will work the same.

If you really don't want it, you can use `replace` with a RegEx to filter `=""`:

```js
el.innerHTML.replace(/=""/g, '')
```

Comment: even when i change them the output is still the same

Comment: Then u must have applied it incorrectly, check your code.